# Exclude route from authentication in Compojure with friend?

Tags: clojure, basic-authentication, compojure

I'm protecting a couple of HTTP routes created with [compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) by basic authentication using the [friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) library. It looks something like this:

```
(defroutes my-routes
             (context "/ctx" []
                      (GET "/x" [] ...)
                      (GET "/y" [] ...)
                      (GET "/z" [] ...)))

(let [friend-auth-cfg {:allow-anon?             false
                       :unauthenticated-handler #(workflows/http-basic-deny "Unauthorized" %)
                       :workflows               [(workflows/http-basic
                                                   :credential-fn #(creds/bcrypt-credential-fn {"username" {:password (creds/hash-bcrypt "password")}} %)
                                                   :realm "My realm")]}
      my-route (-> (wrap-defaults my-routes api-defaults)
                   (friend/authenticate friend-auth-cfg))]
   (run-jetty (routes my-route)))
```

What I'd like to do is to exclude the "y" route (`/ctx/y`) from being protected by basic authentication (but x and z should still be protected). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up splitting "my-routes" into two parts:

```
(defroutes protected-routes
             (context "/ctx" []
                      (GET "/x" [] ...)
                      (GET "/z" [] ...)))
```

and:

```
(defroutes unprotected-routes
             (GET "/ctx/y" [] ...))
```

And only apply the `friend/authenticate` middleware to the `protected-routes` and merging them together like this in the end:

```
(run-jetty (routes my-route))
```

Comment: This is what I've usually ended up doing and have seen others do it as well.